# None of the applications in Programs->Startup and HKCU\Run start at boot

Tags: windows-xp, boot, windows-registry

I am on a windows xp machine and all of a sudden, none of the applications in the programs -> startup, HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run start when the machine is booted. I have to go and run them all manually.

I can't figure out what is causing this and it is very annoying to have to start all these apps manually when rebooting.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Start -> Run. Type in msconfig. Go to startup. See if the items match up correctly. Comment back to let me know the outcome.

-Good Luck

Comment: Yes, all the items in there are set to execute in msconfig.

Comment: When you go to msconfig, under the general tab, is "Normal startup" selected under the "Startup selection" area? If not, select that. Comment back to let me know the outcome please.

Comment: sorry for the delay, yes "Normal Startup" is selected